# How do for statements work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am currently using this code for my project but I can help but to feel a for statement could be used instead.

```
$("#login-1").text($("#" + iconId).data("login1"));
$("#login-1").click(function() {
   var send='';
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("name")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("login1")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("username1")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("password1")+"</br>";
   $("#post").html(send);
   cancel();
});

$("#login-2").text($("#" + iconId).data("login2"));
$("#login-2").click(function() {
   var send='';
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("name")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("login2")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("username2")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("password2")+"</br>";
   $("#post").html(send);
   cancel();
});

$("#login-3").text($("#" + iconId).data("login3"));
$("#login-3").click(function() {
   var send='';
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("name")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("login3")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("username3")+"</br>";
   send += $("#" + iconId).data("password3")+"</br>";
   $("#post").html(send);
   cancel();
});
```

The only thing changing in between most of the lines of code are the number on `login# username# password#`

Comment: Your question should be *"How do classes work in HTML"* !

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$("#login-1,#login-2,#login-3").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

And change the code inside based on `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can optimize by creating a function and passing the necessary arguments:

```
function doChanges(number, iconId) {
  $("#login-" + number).text($("#" + iconId).data("login" + number));
  $("#login-" + number).click(function() {
    var send = '';
    send += $("#" + iconId).data("name") + "</br>";
    send += $("#" + iconId).data("login" + number) + "</br>";
    send += $("#" + iconId).data("username" + number) + "</br>";
    send += $("#" + iconId).data("password" + number) + "</br>";
    $("#post").html(send);
    cancel();
  });
}
```

Example:

```
doChanges(1, iconId);
doChanges(2, iconId);
doChanges(3, iconId);
```

I am not sure, if `iconId` is same or changes. If its same, you can remove that from function argument, it will get more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

```
function looping(length) {  
  for(var i=1;i<=length;i++) {
    $("#login-"+i).text($("#" + iconId).data("login"+1));
    $("#login-"+i).click(function() {
       var send='';
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("name")+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("login"+i)+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("username"+i)+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("password"+i)+"</br>";
       $("#post").html(send);
       cancel();
    });
  }
} 
looping(3);
```

I think this is what you are expecting.
A '+' operator will concatenate the variable i which is the number in the loop.
`$("#login-"+i)` Here for first time it will appear as `("#login1")` then for `i=2` it will be `("#login2")` and so on.

Comment: You're right, this is what i am expecting, but this does not work. I don't understand why.

Comment: I've edited the question.Please accept the answer if it solved your question.